# C# trying to solve a Project Euler problem 5

Tags: c#, loops

I'm new at C# and trying to solve:

- What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?
  This is what I wrote

```
            int i = 1;

            while (i % 2 != 0 || i % 3 != 0 || i % 4 != 0 || i % 5 != 0 || i % 6 != 0 || i % 7 != 0 || i % 8 != 0
                || i % 9 != 0 || i % 10 != 0 || i % 11 != 0 || i % 12 != 0 || i % 13 != 0 || i % 14 != 0
                || i % 15 != 0 || i % 16 != 0 || i % 17 != 0 || i % 18 != 0 || i % 19 != 0 || i % 20 != 0)
            {
                i++;
            }
```

It works the answer is right, but can I optimize it
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

approach with Linq

```
while (Enumerable.Range(2,19).Any(x => i % x != 0))
{
    i++;
}
```

Comment: @canton7 the second parameter of `Enumerable.Range` is `count`, not `to` - that's a common mistake

Answer (score 2):

The simplest next step is to take your long list of `i % x != 0` tests and turn it into a loop:

```
bool IsEvenlyDivisible(int value, int range)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= range; i++)
    {
        if (value % i != 0)
        {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int i = 1;
while (!IsEvenlyDivisible(i, 20))
{
    i++;
}
```

You can even turn this `while` loop into a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 1; IsEvenlyDivisible(i, 20); i++)
{
}
```

You can then make the `IsEvenlyDivisible` method simpler using linq, see fubo's answer.